# How to get Wikidata labels by ID using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

How can I get the labels in English or any other language in Wikidata by ID using SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: this is how to use REST API: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-wikidata-item Not sure how to do this using SPARQL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose **wd:Q146190** is your **wikidata entity ID**

#### get the label in a specific language of your specific entity ID:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
SELECT  *
WHERE {
        wd:Q146190 rdfs:label ?label .
        FILTER (langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ) )
      } 
LIMIT 1
```

- [live example in english](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%20%0Aselect%20%20%2a%0Awhere%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ146190%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28%20lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%22EN%22%20%29%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0ALIMIT%201)
- [live example in german](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%20%0Aselect%20%20%2a%0Awhere%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ146190%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28%20lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%22DE%22%20%29%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0ALIMIT%201)

#### get all the labels in any language of your specific entity ID:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  wd:Q146190 rdfs:label ?label 
}
```

here [the link to the live try](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ146190%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FLabel%20.%20%0A%7D) press on play to run the query then you could download a full JSON and get such a rensponse ..only a trunk copied here:

```
{
    "head": {
        "vars": [
            "label"
        ]
    },
    "results": {
        "bindings": [
            {
                "label": {
                    "xml:lang": "ar",
                    "type": "literal",
                    "value": "دوار الشمس الدرني"
                }
            },
            {
                "label": {
                    "xml:lang": "az",
                    "type": "literal",
                    "value": "Kökyumrulu günəbaxan"
                }
            },
          ..etc,etc.
```

#### get labels for each entity ID in a response resultset with  multiple id

in this case you should use the [Label service](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Label_service)

- [example without labels](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fp%20%20%3Fw%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20wd%3AQ30%20p%3AP6%2Fps%3AP6%20%3Fp%20.%0A%20%20%20%3Fp%20wdt%3AP26%20%3Fw%20.%0A%20%7D)
- [example with labels for each entity in the specified language: english](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fp%20%3FpLabel%20%3Fw%20%3FwLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20wd%3AQ30%20p%3AP6%2Fps%3AP6%20%3Fp%20.%0A%20%20%20%3Fp%20wdt%3AP26%20%3Fw%20.%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%7D)

```
SELECT ?p ?pLabel ?w ?wLabel WHERE {
   wd:Q30 p:P6/ps:P6 ?p .
   ?p wdt:P26 ?w .
   SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
   }
 }
```

to use this service add `Label` to the variable ( ie: for `?p` label you must use `?pLabel` then add

```
   SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
   }
```

to the `WHERE` block