# Why variable + Label is not working in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

In the examples of the SPARQL of Wikidata, we have this one:

```
    SELECT ?h ?date 
WHERE 
{
    ?h wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
    ?h wdt:P569 ?date .
    OPTIONAL {?h wdt:P570 ?d } 
    FILTER (?date > "1880-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)
    FILTER (!bound(?d))
}
LIMIT 1000
```

I understand that if you put Label after the name of a variable it shows the label. So, I don't understand why this shows no output:

```
    SELECT ?h ?hLabel ?date ...
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This feature is provided by Wikidata-specific [service](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Label_service).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of that specific feature for Label after the variable name.

However, for rdfs:label, you can to inculde the `rdfs:label` in your query. Add the following line: `?h rdfs:label ?hLabel.`:

```
SELECT ?h ?hLabel ?date WHERE 
{
    ?h wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
    ?h wdt:P569 ?date .      
    ?h rdfs:label ?hLabel. 
    OPTIONAL {?h wdt:P570 ?d } 
    FILTER (?date > "1880-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)
    FILTER (!bound(?d))
}
LIMIT 1000
```

If you want labels in a specific language, e.g. for English add `FILTER (langMatches( lang(?hLabel), "EN" ) )`

[Here is a **stackoverflow** intersting answer about labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268148/how-to-get-wikidata-labels-by-id-using-sparql).

Comment: It solved that issue, but now there is añother one. This is my new query:
`
SELECT ?h ?hLabel ?date WHERE 

{

    ?h wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .

    ?h wdt:P569 ?date .    
  
    ?h rdfs:label ?hLabel. 

    OPTIONAL {?h wdt:P570 ?d } 

    FILTER (?date > "1880-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)

    FILTER (!bound(?d))


}

LIMIT 1000
`
Now in the answer I have some elements more than once. I tried `DISTINCT` and  ` SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }`. But neither is working. Thanks

Comment: I think it is because the language. Just add the language filter I mentioned in the answer to include only English results. Or add ?lang to the select, and then add BIND ( lang(?hLabel) as ?lang) in the where clause.

Comment: @JackGreen if you use the Wikidata label service, then you don't need to use the `rdfs:label` triple pattern.

Comment: Thank you. I discovered that you mean this:

   `SERVICE wikibase:label {
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }.`