# How to get labels from wikidata?

Tags: wikidata, multilabel-classification

I want to use wikidata for MultiLabelClassify. I don't understand the struct of wikidata, I want get all the labels from a entity of wikidata. Could you give me some suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Wikidata labels by ID using SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268148/how-to-get-wikidata-labels-by-id-using-sparql)

Answer (score 0):

Either use Wikidata Query Service (see link by Kiran) oder use the MediaWiki API.

With the MediaWiki API, you can get all labels of an entity by calling:
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&props=labels&ids=ENTITYID

For example for entity Q42:
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&props=labels&ids=Q42